# Deployed on Azure bot does not response

Tags: c#, botframework

I start investigating BotFramework and encountered one annoying issue.

1. Created "Hello world" bot. 
   Here if the code

   ```
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
   {
       if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
       {
           ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
           // calculate something for us to return
           int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

           // return our reply to the user
           Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");
           await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
       }
       else
       {
           HandleSystemMessage(activity);
       }
       var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
       return response;
   }
   ```

It works fine locally

2. Deployed it on Azure.
3. Set correct BotId, MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword parameters in web.config.
4. URL with my bot is http://funnyskypebot20171026010946.azurewebsites.net and it looks it works

But when i try to "communicate" with bit via Bot Framework Channel Emulator i do not receive any messages back ... 
What could be wrong ? Please advise.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the emulator log panel?

Comment: @stuartd no. i have not any errors in emulator panel

Comment: What is your bot handle?

Comment: can you try with https endpoint?

Comment: @KienChu I have already tried it. Result is the same. Message could not be sent without any details what is wrong and what happened

Comment: @JasonSowers It should handle common text messages. `CreateReply($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters")`

Comment: @Disappointed: it's more of the configuration error rather than code error. I suggest you to test the bot on the `botframework` portal (built-in web chat) or you can set up ngrok to test your **live endpoint** in your emulator

Comment: @KienChu I just try to test it with build-in web chat and i have the same behavior as with Bot Framework Channel Emulator. "Message could not be send". I try to set different messaging endpoints. https://funnyskypebot20171026010946.azurewebsites.net/api/messages and https://funnyskypebot20171026010946.azurewebsites.net. But result is the same

Comment: @KienChu web chat now shows me the following issue "10/27/2017, 12:47:28 PM There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code InternalServerError"

Comment: I was asking for the bot handle, the name of your bot I tried to look up  `funnyskypebot`  but was unable to find it in the admin portal

Comment: @JasonSowers Hi :) Sorry for late response. I had day offs. My bot handle is "IhorAndriyBohdanIhor".

Comment: @JasonSowers That is weird. I just reinstall Bot framework Emulator and now i receive bot responses successfully ! However i still got "Internal Server error" when try to communicate with it via Web Chat channel ... I am totally confused ...

Comment: @JasonSowers I wanted to test it using skype, but it turns out that my country is not available for skype bots ... Weird, why ?! I am from Ukraine, by the way

Answer (score 2):

I assume you already followed the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/deploy-dotnet-bot-visual-studio for deployment to Azure.

Have you seen this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/debug-bots-emulator with regards to debugging remotely using ngrok?

If you are using Visual Studio, on the toolbar, you can click on 'View -> Server Explorer'. Under 'Azure -> App Service', you should see your resource group there. Under your resource group, you should see your app service. Right-click and select 'Attach Debugger' so that you can view the output ('View -> Output') and debug your deployed app service.

Comment: Thank you for tip ! I tried it but i could not connect to Azure with debugger ... Probably the reason is that we have local network limitations ...

Answer (score 0):

Internal server error generally means there is some sort of issue with your code. Try debugging locally using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download).  You can change your endpoint in the [dev portal](https://dev.botframework.com/bots/settings?id=IhorAndriyBohdanIhor) to the one that ngrok generates when you use this command `ngrok http 3979 -host-header="localhost:3979"` change to the port your bot runs on.

More info:
[Blog Post](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/)
[Blog Post](https://www.robinosborne.co.uk/2016/09/19/debugging-botframework-locally-using-ngrok/)